# can i install the .exe file without user interaction

Tags: c#, installation, exe, silent

Can I install the .exe file without user interaction (means without click on the next or install button)
I have write the code to call .exe file but, it doesn't install silently in background.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Downloads\teamViewer.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/S";
p.Start();
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.WaitForExit();
```

Why exe not run in background, with this code?

Comment: Which programming language? Which operating system? Why do you have a space before `teamViewer` ?

Comment: That depends a little on the installer. It must support a silent setup. Not every program can handle that. Especially for the free version of teamviewer I cannot imagine that this is possible.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I have use C#.net on windows 7.and FileName Contains the path of the exe, space is not in the actual code

Comment: Please edit your question to tag it appropriately, and to remove typos in the code.

Comment: @rekire,thanx but is it possible for any other software to install without any user interaction. i.e auto click on next or install button

Comment: I expect that the commercial version will support that. While installing the free version may result a licence problem caused by the non commercial usage.

Comment: Maybe assignment of `p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow` should occur *before* call to `p.Start` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, i put the `p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow` before the `p.Start();` but problem remains the same

Comment: Maybe it's me but 'silent install' sounds like the exe is something nasty

Comment: @JeroenMoons, i just want to know,how the program install on the system without user's click.because mostly s/w has only next-next-next button clicks,so i want to reduce that time..and i think team viewer is not a nasty exe.

Comment: If you have a corporate license for teamviewer, you should have an msi installer file which probably can be installed silently provided you have admin rights. (usually by running msiexec setup.msi /quiet)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a silent install with the EXE you download from the website.

You have to use the one that it extracts into your

> %temp%\TeamViewer\VersionX\TeamViewer_.exe

As of version 7 `%temp%\TeamViewer\Version7\TeamViewer_.exe`. This one supports the `/S` argument, but there is another problem : UAC confirmation dialog and as far as I know you can't bypass this with code (unless your app is already running with admin privileges. You can use an application manifest for that).